# Upper bound on norm of time varying square matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I've searched for this but I'm having some trouble following the answers from other threads. It's probably quite simple. I'm looking for an upper bound on the eucledian norm of a square,real, n x n matrix, **A**. The matrix is time varying, with the variables in this matrix are all bounded. How do I go about this? I am very mathematically rusty.

Best Regards MC

Answer (score 0):

We have $A(t)=(a_{ij}(t))$ and there are numbers $c_{ij} \ge 0$ such that

$|a_{ij}(t)| \le c_{ij}$ for all $t$ in the domain of $A$

($i,j =1,...,n$).

Define $C=(c_{ij})$.

It is your turn to show that

$||A(t)|| \le ||C||$ for all $t$ in the domain of $A$ .

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\|A\|_{Fr} &= \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2} \leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^nc_{ij}^2}\leqslant n^2c
\end{align*}

With $|a_{ij}|\leqslant c_{ij}$, the bound of each element, and $c:=\max_{ij}c_{ij}$.